# HTTrack gives 404 on unicode urls with german special characters

Tags: url, unicode, httrack

I've realized that HTTrack can't download files if urls have special characters in them, like german `ß` - it returns a 404 response.

Errors look like on screenshot:

[image]

Is there any setting in HTTrack to make it able to deal with such characters?

ps: I found a similar thread, but without an answer:

[Httrack faulty when encountering japanese encoded URLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760120/)

Answer (score 1):

HTTrack seems to be able to get files errorfree from urls with special characters, only if you don't run a "real" domain crawl, but:

- firstly create an url list,
- save it as `iso-8859-1`,
- than let HTTrack crawl this list

If HTTrack will explore urls by its own, it will run into 404 errors on urls with special characters - at least i wasn't able to get them errorfree. Maybe somebody will provide a magic setting ;)